# Quadratic dual help

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensors, duality-theorems

I'm trying to figure out the whether the quadratic dual of the following algebra is anti-commutative.

My algebra is $A=T(V)/J$ where $J=\langle I\rangle$ and $I\subseteq\bigwedge^2(V)$. Firstly I think it follows simply by counting dimensions ($V$ is finite dimensional here) that $S^2(V)\subseteq J^{\perp}$. However, is this enough to say that the quadratic dual is anti-commutative, is there more to prove, or is it false?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I had missed that you were asking about its quadratic dual, rather than about the algebra itself.